# Can this multistep SORT JCL be condensed?

Tags: mainframe, jcl

I'm using the following JCL to transform the results of a DSNTEPZ query into a required layout, as well as slap on a header and trailer. I've been able to complete my task, but it feels unwieldy. Any JCL wizards out there able to condense any of these steps? I really hate the final sort, but I can't find any way to output a date inside the header of format MMYYYY.

```
//**********remove extra output lines/reformat   *******************
//SORT     EXEC PGM=SORT,
//             REGION=2000K
//SORTIN   DD  DSN=&&SORT1IN,DISP=(OLD,DELETE,DELETE)    * pds of query results
//SORTWK01 DD  UNIT=SYSDA,SPACE=(CYL,(20,5))
//SORTOUT  DD  DSN=&&SORT1OUT,
//             DISP=(NEW,PASS,DELETE),
//             AVGREC=K,LRECL=100,
//             SPACE=(100,(900,100),RLSE)
//SYSOUT   DD  SYSOUT=*
//SYSIN    DD  *
  SORT FIELDS=COPY -
  INCLUDE COND=(97,1,CH,EQ,C'1',OR,    * This removes the 'informational' Query lines
                97,1,CH,EQ,C'2',OR,
                97,1,CH,EQ,C'0') -
  OUTREC FIELDS=(C'DTL',32,9,71,10,5X,49,19,2X,84,4,89,2,      *Arranging the Output
              92,2,97,1,43X)
/*
//************************ add hdr/trl  ***********************
//SORT2    EXEC PGM=SORT,
//             REGION=2000K
//SORTIN   DD  DSN=&&SORT1OUT,DISP=(OLD,DELETE,DELETE)
//SORTWK01 DD  UNIT=SYSDA,SPACE=(CYL,(20,5))
//SORTOUT  DD  DSN=&&SORT2OUT,
//             DISP=(NEW,PASS,DELETE),
//             AVGREC=K,LRECL=100,
//             SPACE=(100,(900,100),RLSE)
//SYSOUT   DD  SYSOUT=*
//SYSIN    DD  *
  OPTION COPY
  OUTFIL REMOVECC,
  HEADER1=(C'HEADERENE',DATENS=(DM4),19:82X),
  TRAILER1=(C'TRAILER',COUNT=(M11,LENGTH=9),83X)
/*
//************************ CONVERT DATE  ***********************
//SORT3    EXEC PGM=SORT,
//             REGION=2000K
//SORTIN   DD  DSN=&&SORT2OUT,DISP=(OLD,DELETE,DELETE)
//SORTWK01 DD  UNIT=SYSDA,SPACE=(CYL,(20,5))
//SORTOUT  DD  SYSOUT=*
//SYSOUT   DD  SYSOUT=*
//SYSIN    DD  *
  OPTION COPY
  OUTREC IFTHEN=(WHEN=(1,7,CH,EQ,C'HEADERE'),
         BUILD=(1,9,12,6,85X))
/*
//
```

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, JCL is the stuff starting with // (and also /*) in columns one and two. What you want is SORT Control Cards.

```
  OPTION COPY 
  INCLUDE COND=(97,1,CH,EQ,C'1',OR, 
                97,1,CH,EQ,C'2',OR, 
                97,1,CH,EQ,C'0') 

  INREC BUILD=(C'DTL', 
               32,9, 
               71,10, 
               5X, 
               49,19, 
               2X, 
               84,4, 
               89,2, 
               92,2, 
               97,1, 
               43X) 

  OUTFIL REMOVECC, 
      HEADER1=(01:C'HEADERENE', 
               10:DATENS=(DM4), 
               100:X), 
      TRAILER1=(C'TRAILER', 
                COUNT=(M11,LENGTH=9),
                100:X)
```

That's your first two steps.I've removed the spurious "-"s, I've only removed your comments as they didn't fit, you can have inline comments as you had done, or an entire line, starting with an *. I've changed FIELDS to BUILD (FIELDS has been around since Day One, and has multiple uses in different contexts: BUILD has been around for 10 years, and every time you see it (on INREC, OUTREC or OUTFIL) it only means BUILD.

As you have discovered, the content of HEADER1 is limited to what is allowed. Either live with that, or if the content of HEADER1 is not what you want, you can make your own header.

You will: temporarily extend the records to include a SEQNUM, which is large enough to comfortably represent all your records: in OUTFIL, identify the first record, and use the slash-operator (/) to output two records, first the header, which you format how you want, then the actual data record (remembering to exclude any data that you have temporarily extended by).